# What do i need to run multiple computers as one?

Tags: parallel-processing, cluster-computing

How can i run multiple computers as one? 
i.e. one "master" which issues commands and one or more slaves who do what they are told to do. 
also, How do the distributed computingsystems in supercomputers do this?

EDIT:
I found [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beowulf_%28computing%29), [this](http://idea.uab.es/mcreel/PelicanHPC/) and [this](http://www.antionline.com/showthread.php?t=260223) and now i wonder, is there something similar that will run parallel programs like hash cracking? Mostly a software designed for these types of cloud computing systems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In distributed computing systems, broadly speaking, there is no concept of master-slave, the way you describe.
It is a set of distinct autonomous machines (or to define it differently a set of HW or SW modules running at different computers) that work "together" to the same goal.
They achieve this by network communication.
It is as if you had a **single** software running (through all the machines) and the various processing modules of this software "running" in separate machines (as opossed to separate threads or processes in the same machine).
Parallel computing is not the same concept as distributed computing, a difference being that in distributed systems each machine uses its own memory.
Supercomputer is a term usually refering to hardware capabilities.

Comment: And you don't have any idea of how i can accomplish my goal of a "raid 0" for whole computers?